# Exception Could not find class 'java.awt.font.FontRenderContext', referenced from method org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil for hSSFSheet.shiftRows

Tags: java, android, apache-poi, noclassdeffounderror, shift

In Android app, wanted to append text in existing Xls file at start, and for that trying to shift rows in an existing Excel file.

**using eclipse**

But first getting below warnings

```
E/dalvikvm(27775): Could not find class 'java.awt.font.FontRenderContext', 
referenced from method org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.<clinit>
W/dalvikvm(27775): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 7013 
(Ljava/awt/font/FontRenderContext;) in Lorg/apache/poi/ss/util/SheetUtil;
```

And then Exception

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.shiftMerged(HSSFSheet.java:1207)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.shiftRows(HSSFSheet.java:1303)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.shiftRows(HSSFSheet.java:1262)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.shiftRows(HSSFSheet.java:1242)
at com.jd.utils.ExportUtils.createAlertXlsForMachine(ExportUtils.java:177)
at com.jd.utils.ExportUtils.moveDataOlderThanNDaysToXls(ExportUtils.java:86)
at com.jd.activity.SplashScreen$AsyncExportDeleteData.doInBackground(SplashScreen.java:55)
at com.jd.activity.SplashScreen$AsyncExportDeleteData.doInBackground(SplashScreen.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.font.FontRenderContext
at org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.<clinit>(SheetUtil.java:75)
... 14 more
```

for **HSSFSheet.shiftRows**

```
FileInputStream fileInS = new FileInputStream(outputXlsFile);
HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInS);
HSSFSheet  hSSFSheet= hwb.getSheet("alert");
hSSFSheet.shiftRows(0, 4, 1);
```

Is there any other way to shift excel lines?​

Or is there any other way to append text at start of existing file?

Also can't use any other libs than **using Apache-Poi now**.

Comment: Shift the rows on a "real" computer, then send the pre-shifted workbook to the phone for editing?

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks, but think I can't do that because the code is in Android app, so will be executed on Android device Api 14+

Comment: Also I'm not able to import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext; on my computer in eclipse.

Comment: Because AWT library does not ship with Android.

Comment: So your options are: Send the file somewhere which does have a proper JVM, re-write that bit of POI to use whatever Android offers instead of AWT, or find an AWT implementation for Android to deploy. Well, or persuade Google to finish implementing Java on Android, but that's a bit harder...

Comment: @EugenPechanec so is there any open source library that after adding it issue will be solved

Comment: @Gagravarr Thank very much, but all you options are Mission Impossible for me now, looks like have to find an alternative to 'shiftRows', thanks by the way

Comment: @centic I know(realized) 'NOW' that it's a duplicate(rather similar) to question you pointed, but i didn't realize that when I didn't know the answer and so wasted my 30 mins to post this question, so please stackoverflow should keep questions like this 'alive'(not closed because of duplicate) so that many other who will face this problem in future will not waste their 30 mins each.

Comment: A duplicate question will not be hidden, it just will not be possible to add answers and will have a prominent note on top that it is a duplicate...